# Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

`tensorflow` version 2.3.1 `numpy` version 1.19.5 `keras` version 2.4.3

I want to see the middle layer of the `keras` model.

```
train_data = tf.constant([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
train_labels = tf.constant([[0], [0], [0], [1]])
input_tensor = Input(shape=2)
x1 = Dense(10, kernel_initializer=initializer)(input_tensor)
x2 = Activation('sigmoid')(x1)
output_tensor = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=initializer)(x2)
model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=output_tensor)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['acc'])
print('weight', model.get_weights())
history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=800)

#error
test = tf.constant(x2)
print(x2)
```

we got

> NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (activation/Sigmoid:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported

Changing the version of `numpy` does not solve the problem.

Comment: It's not a `numpy` problem!  Do you know what a `symbolic Tensor` is?  If not, you may need to study the `tensorflow` basics some more.  Also, when asking about an error, do us a favor and show WHERE the error occurs.  At least the line in your code, better yet the whole traceback.  We shouldn't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

x2 is a keras tensor ,edited the error part to print its values

```
#error part edited

import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
x2 = K.print_tensor(x2, message='x2 = ')
print(x2)
```

attaching [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/2f5b7830db806b5fa2f6022c689193a2/stack_66863897.ipynb#scrollTo=ZXxvlraE7c2T) for reference

Comment: could you help me, please? A similar issue https://github.com/shamangary/FSA-Net/issues/76